# What is the difference between calling operator methods and calling other methods of the parent class not implemented in the child class?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, derived-class, base-class

In the following code, calling `operator()` with `int` on the derived class does not compile, however, calling `get()` with either `int` or `double` on the derived class works fine.

Both the `operator()` with `int` input and `get()` are only implemented in the base class and not in the derived one.

Keeping or removing the virtual keyword does not affect the outcome.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual double operator()(double& x) { return 0; }
  virtual int operator()(int& i) { return 1; }
  virtual double get(double& x) { return 2; }
  virtual int get(int& i) { return 3; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  double operator()(double& x) { return 4; }
};

int main() {

  B b;
  A& a = *(&b);

  double x = 100.0;
  int i = 1;

  std::cout << a(x) << "\n";
  std::cout << b(x) << "\n";
  std::cout << a(i) << "\n";
  std::cout << "b(i)" << "\n"; // this line does not compile when it is b(i) instead of "b(i)" 
  std::cout << a.get(x) << "\n";
  std::cout << b.get(x) << "\n";
  std::cout << a.get(i) << "\n";
  std::cout << b.get(i) << "\n";

}
```

Is there a fundamental difference between operator methods and other methods that causes this issue?

Comment: This is the same for functions and operator.  TL;DR of the dupe: As soon as you introduce the name of the overload set in the derived class, all base class overloads are hidden.